# rpart decision tree learner in R: Is there any way to restrict it to only use a variable once

Tags: r, cart

Is there a way in `rpart` to force the variables only used once when doing the splits?

A data scientist named Tao once [asked](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/quot-rpart-quot-how-to-use-each-variable-only-once-td2216933.html):

> This is how the question came about.  Often, the tree constructed
>   uses the same variable (say X1) for the first and second splits, for
>   example.  However, due to practical reason, the researcher doesn't
>   like this.  The prefer to see the second split using other variables
>   (say X2).  Therefore the question.  I understand the performance will
>   suffer.  However if there is a performance improvement for the tree
>   with X1 as 1st split and X2 as 2nd split comparing the tree with one
>   single split using X1, I guess it's still a reasonable thing to do,
>   right?

Is there an answer for Tao and myself?

Comment: You introduced a new tag [rtree].  Can you please add a tag wiki?

Comment: I removed that tag.

Comment: Not exactly what you ask but it might help. In the rpart function there is a cost parameter. The cost parameter is a vector that indicates the cost of making a split for each feature. This way you can encorage the tree to avoid using certain features when splitting.